# GitHub способ перемещения файла из одного репозитория в другой

Tags: git, файлы, github, репозиторий, copy

Всем доброго времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какая-нибудь возможность перемещать файлы на GitHub из одного репозитория в другой.
Допустим, у меня есть репозиторий BlackJack
https://github.com/MaximPravenkiy/BlackJack
Файл из этого репозитория мне необходимо переместить в репозиторий Kazino (в котором также есть свой файл)
https://github.com/MaximPravenkiy/Kazino
Есть ли какая-нибудь возможность сделать это?

Comment: Конечно есть. Скачиваете файл из одного репозитория и добавляете его в другой.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Прошу прощения, я опечатался. Внёс изменения в заголовок

Comment: @AlexeyTen правильно ли я понимаю, что в таком случае история коммитов не будет отображена в репозитории, в который я перенесу файлы?

Comment: Да. История коммитов это «свойство» репозитория, а не отдельных файлов.